# How to launch new terminal window (OS X) with different profile

Tags: terminal, osx-mavericks

I have a certain default terminal profile (look) that I like to use all the time. However when I use VIM I have a different profile that I have to trigger via preferences in Terminal.app.

What I'd like to have is .command file that would open new terminal window with that profile enabled, so I could just drop the file in dock or launch it via alias in other terminal session.

I could also accept AppleScript solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load up the terminal profile that you like and want to use for `vim`. Then go to `Shell->Export Settings` at the top left of the screen and save that profile on your Desktop. Now, whenever you want to use it, just double-click the profile on your Desktop.

[image]